# How to convert padding bottom on a DIV into negative margin on its containing DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So I want a DIV's (splashSquareTitle) padding-bottom to translate into it's containing DIV's (splashSquare) negative margin-top, I'm not sure but is the percentages creating the problem? any help is much appreciated.

I'm not trying to get the DIV's (splashSquareTitle) padding-bottom to swap out to the other DIV's (splashSquare) margin-top, I want it to emulate DIV's (splashSquareTitle) padding-bottom.

HTML

```
<div class="splashSquare">
  <div class="splashSquareTitle greenBG">
    <img src="img/placeholder/beach_icon.svg" alt="icon small" />
    <h5>Playground</h5>
  </div>
  <img src="img/placeholder/splash_square_placeholder.jpg" class="splashSquareImage" alt="splash square image" />
  <div class="splashSquareInfo">
    <h5>TiPai Playground</h5>
    <h5>Henderson, Auckland</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="splashSquareBuffer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.splashSquare{
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  max-width:320px;
  color:#ffffff;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px #ffffff;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 1px #ffffff;
}
.splashSquareTitle{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom:16%;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(function(){
  var splashheaderheight = $("div.splashSquareTitle").paddingBottom();
  var marginTop = parseInt(splashheaderheight) * -1;
  $("div.splashSquare").css("marginTop", marginTop + "px");
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var splashheaderheight = $("div.splashSquareTitle").paddingBottom();
    var marginTop = parseInt(splashheaderheight) * -1;
    $("div.splashSquare").css("marginTop", marginTop + "px");
  });
});
```

here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JAVK/8Z5Ey/)

Comment: First and foremost, please provide a FIDDLE... I'll make one for you... there you go [fiddlelink](http://jsfiddle.net/SAQjk/3/)

Comment: @JVK Design Does not appear where `.paddingBottom()` function is defined ? Have tried `.css("paddingBottom", "value")` ? Thanks for sharing

Comment: @guest271314 I noticed that as well. .css('paddding-bottom') works.

Comment: Sorry! @Nicholas Hazel I've now added a jsfiddle at the bottom of the question, I'm a real novice when it comes to jquery so I do struggle to see what's in plain view for you experienced folk.

Comment: Percentages can be dangerous if used improperly. I'll take a look tomorrow. Just so I know, you're trying to duplicate `margin-bottom` for two elements? Furthmore, jQuery seems a bit... robust... for this. Ever thought of a CSS only solution and just add the `class` with `jQuery`?

Comment: @guest271314 I tried that and it didn't seem to work for me. No change was made.

Comment: @Nicholas Hazel Yea maybe percentages is where I'm running into trouble, it's a fully responsive site so the majority of the site is in percentages. I'm trying to find the amount of pixels the padding-bottom is (as it's in percentage in css), copy that amount and then make it the negative margin-top of another element and obviously to adjust on window resize.

The problem with trying to do it in css is that say 16% height for one element will be a different 16% height on another depending on it's parent element.

Comment: @JVKDesign Perhaps am not interpreting the requirement accurately. Do not see where `margin-top` is defined in css ? Could make a jsfiddle ? Please clarify requirement. Thanks for sharing

Comment: @JVKDesign Please describe the visual effect of "translate into it's containing DIV's (splashSquare) negative margin-top," ? What does "translate" comprise ? Thanks

Comment: Pretend you want **25px** `top-margin`. What elements do you want this on? Or are you trying to capture from an external source? Do you want `margin-bottom` of `a` be the same as `margin-top` of `b`?

Comment: @Nicholas Hazel thanks for your help and sorry for the confusing explanation. guest271314 figured it out and posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If interpreting requirement accurately, apply (defined) `css` property of `div.splashSquareTitle` `padding-bottom` to (undefined) `css` property of `div.splashSquare` `margin-top` ?

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function($) {
    $.fn.getProp = function(prop) {
      var props = window.getComputedStyle (
        $(this).get(0)
      ).getPropertyValue(prop);
      return props
    };
})(jQuery);
  function translatePadding() {
    var splashheaderheight = $("div.splashSquareTitle").getProp("padding-bottom");
      return $("div.splashSquare").css("margin-top", "-"+splashheaderheight);
  };
  translatePadding();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    return translatePadding()
  });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/f2tLS/

Hope this helps

Comment: nailed it @guest271314 just one more question, I tried to add

Comment: @JVKDesign Hi. Does the piece fulfill the requirement ?  Please clarify. Thanks for sharing

Comment: nailed it @guest271314 just one more question, I tried to add
`return $("div.splashSquare").css("margin-bottom", +splashheaderheight);` to just below `return $("div.splashSquare").css("margin-top", "-"+splashheaderheight);`. The reason for this is that there are more of the div.squareSplash that sit underneath each other and the ones below are now sitting on top of the ones above.

Comment: @JVKDesign Not exactly certain about integrating an additional requirement, with the parameters briefly described in comment ? Perhaps clearly describe the additional requirement at another question ? Is requirement of original question fulfilled , accepted ? Happy to help with follow-up at another question, if able. Thanks

Comment: I figured it out, I wanted to return multiple values and just had to put both in `[]` thanks for your help, really appreciate it!